# Weird exception after updated Autofac

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I have an MVC4 application before,
I've updated version of Autofac, every thing worked ok, now i have this weird exception.

Please help!?

```
Method not found: 'Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3<!0,!1,!2> Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3.InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(System.Object)'.



Line 22:             var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
Line 23:             builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
Line 24:             builder.Register(x => new AuthorizationService()).As<IAuthService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
Line 25:             builder.Register(x => new HeaderRepository()).As<IUIHeaderRepository>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
Line 26:             builder.Register(x => new PageBuilder()).As<IUPageBuilder>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Stack trace:

```
 [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3<!0,!1,!2> Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3.InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(System.Object)'.]
       Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RegistrationExtensions.InstancePerHttpRequest(IRegistrationBuilder`3 registration) +0
       Application.UI.Web.Services.HttpDependencyInjectionResolver.RegisterDependencies() in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\MyProject\Application.UI.Web\Services\HttpDependencyInjectionResolver.cs:24
       Application.UI.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\MyProject\Application.UI.Web\Global.asax.cs:42

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: 'Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3<!0,!1,!2> Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3.InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(System.Object)'.]
       System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9859441
       System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
       System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
       System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
       System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: 'Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3<!0,!1,!2> Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3.InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(System.Object)'.]
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873784
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You also need to update [Autofac.Integration.Mvc](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration) to the corresponding version.

If that doesn't help, make sure that the new versions of both files are actually in the folder the code is executed from. Maybe one of them couldn't be copied to the IIS folder?

Comment: Are you using NuGet to manage your references or are you manually doing it?

Comment: Try removing Autofac and Autofac.Mvc4 and just adding Autofac.Mvc4 back. It will automatically install the correct version of Autofac.

Comment: @IamStalker: If it doesn't help, please check the second paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might well be that you are using asp.net mvc 3 which has incompatibilities with method `InstancePerHttpRequest()`

which is found autofac mvc 3 contrib (forgot the name of the package).
In my case upgrading to the mvc 4 fixed the issue.