# After upgrade to latest version of Autofac project is broken

Tags: moq, autofac

Ok So I have spent the day trying to resolve this problem with Autofac, Moq and Moq.Contrib.Indy I have been using Nuget to upgrade my various projects to the latest versions of things including Autofac.

my Project refers to the following: -

```
    <Reference Include="Autofac, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Autofac.3.5.2\lib\net40\Autofac.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Autofac.Integration.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.3\lib\net45\Autofac.Integration.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AutofacContrib.CommonServiceLocator, Version=2.6.3.862, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>          
 <HintPath>..\packages\Autofac.CommonServiceLocator.Indy.2.6.3.863\lib\net40\AutofacContrib.CommonServiceLocator.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

I have followed the advice given in this question [Weird exception after updated Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754479/weird-exception-after-updated-autofac?s=1|0.5653)

However, when I run my unit tests I get an error as follows.

```
SetUp : System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3<!0,!1,!2> Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3.PropertiesAutowired(Autofac.PropertyWiringFlags)'. at Moq.Contrib.Indy.AutoMockContainer.<Create>b__0<T>(ContainerBuilder builder) at Moq.Contrib.Indy.AutoMockContainer.Update(Action`1 registration)    at Moq.Contrib.Indy.AutoMockContainer.ResolveOrCreate(Action`1 registration) at Moq.Contrib.Indy.AutoMockContainer.Create()    at NUnitTests.TestContext`1..ctor() in TestContext.cs: line 24    at NUnitTests.AccountsAccountLutTests..ctor()
```

I have completely removed ALL references to Autofac and Moq from the App.config, the packages.config and the .csproj file, then I have re added the required references using NuGet so that the dependencies are correctly done. However, it seems that no matter what I do I get run time errors trying to run my tests... It just seems and feels as though the latest Autofac is broken? any advice gratefully received I would love to get my tests working again.

Or are these things not compatible anymore and I should give up and go in a different direction?

Regards Julian

Answer (score 1):

The package [Moq.Contrib.Indy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq.Contrib.Indy) references [Autofac.CommonServiceLocator.Indy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.CommonServiceLocator.Indy) which, in turn, specifies that it references Autofac 2.6.3.862.

[Autofac 2.6.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/2.6.3.862) is pretty old. June 2012 old. A lot has changed in Autofac since then. Chances are these "Indy" packages you're referencing haven't kept up with ensuring they are correctly forward-compatible with newer Autofac, which is why you're seeing this issue.

I'm guessing the "Indy" packages need to actually specify *not only* that they require Autofac >= 2.6.3, but *also* that they require Autofac < 3.0.0.

I would recommend in the short term reverting back to the older version of Autofac you were using. Long term, I'd recommend contacting [the author of those Indy packages](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/jbatte47) to see if you can get them updated to be compatible with the latest Autofac.